# gorm many2many and additional fields in association table

Tags: postgresql, go, model, go-gorm

I have a many2many association (it is used to return JSON). It's declared in a model:

```
// models/school.go
type School struct {
    ID                int      `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Name              string `gorm:"not null"`
    Accreditations    []Accreditation `gorm:"many2many:school_accreditation;"` 
}
```

It works well. I have the association returned in the json. The problem is that I have an additional field in the `school_accreditation` table but it **isn't** included in the response.

I have tried to declare a model for the association like proposed in [this  answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55339916/633864):

```
// models/schoolAccreditation.go
package models

import "time"

// many to many
type SchoolAccreditation struct {
    StartedAt time.Time `gorm:"not null"`
}
```

But it doesn't work so far. Is there some additional configuration to declare? Or to modify?

Comment: *"The problem is that I have an additional field in the `school_accreditation` table but **it is included** in the response."* Is that a typo? Or are you saying that you want to *exclude* a field from json? If so, you can use the `json:"-"` field tag to achieve that.

Comment: Sorry, I have modified "it isn't included". I want the additional field to appear in the json response. Thanks for pointing out the typo. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answering to myself, I added the field in the linked model as "ignore" and it works, the column is automatically retrieved from the association table.

```
type Accreditation struct {
    // "accreditation" table
    ID          int `gorm:"primary_key"`
    Name        string
    Description string
    // "school_accreditation table", so the field is set as ignore with "-"
    EndAt       time.Time `gorm:"-"`
}
```